# Is there a way to force a server to stop executing a script?

Tags: php, ajax

I am sending an AJAX get() request and I want to be able to abort it. Using the AJAX abort() I can force the client to stop listening to the response. Is there a way to make the server stop executing the php script?

Answer (score 2):

You can use the function [connection_aborted()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.connection-aborted.php) to detect if the client is still connected and then die(), exit() or whatever if the client has.